# Pipe to filter array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

Say I have the data as shown below:

```
[
    { id: '1', plate: 'plate1', time: 20 },
    { id: '1', plate: 'plate2', time: 30 },
    { id: '1', plate: 'plate3', time: 30 },
    { id: '2', plate: 'plate4', time: 30 },
    { id: '2', plate: 'plate5', time: 30 },
    { id: '2', plate: 'plate6', time: 30 }
]
```

I want to filter my data using a custom pipe.  But the filter should be not limit to a certain field. It should be dynamic.  Say, if I entered "1" in my search box all that has a 1 value should be shown.  Say I entered "plate" all that has a plate value will be shown. And say I entered "PLATE1" only 1 entry will be shown.

I know that it's possible, but the question is how to do it in Angular.

Comment: pipes are not meant to be used as filters

Comment: so what can you suggest then?

Comment: Instead of creating pipes you can use array.filter binded to change event of the textbox.

Comment: @Sreemat is correct

Comment: that sounds ok.  But what would be the filter looks like?

Comment: Nothing of this has anything to do with TypeScript. TypeScript is just a typing layer on top of JavaScript.

Comment: Check this out: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/